# Java GetFile returns incorrect filename after using SetFile

Tags: java, awt, filenames, filedialog

I have some Java code:

```
public static String getSaveFilePath(String title2)
  {
  FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Save As...", 1);
    fd.setFilenameFilter(new FilenameFilter() {
      public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".mp3");
      }
    });
    fd.setFile(title2 + ".mp3");
    fd.setVisible(true);
    String str3 = fd.getFile();
    String str4 = fd.getDirectory();
    if (str4 == null) return null;
    str3 = str3.replace(".mp3", "");
    str3 = str3 + ".mp3";
    String str5 = str3;
    File localFile = new File(str4, str5);
    return localFile.getPath();
}
```

The problem is when I use `setFile()` to set the filename to

```
NBA - In the Zone P.L. (Video by JESSExAKAxViCiOUS)
```

before the dialog is shown, and when the dialog is shown, I save the file as `abc.mp3` 
and I use `getFile()` again, I get `SExAKAxViCiOUS).mp3` - where as it should return the name of the file I selected to save to, `abc.mp3`.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Also if you have a better cross platform solution to show a save file dialog please share it with me.

Comment: *"Also if you have a better cross platform solution to show a save file dialog please share it with me."*  `JFileChooser` part of Swing.  Oddly, you have added the Swing tag yet used an AWT based component.

Comment: @AndrewThompson But JFileChooser won't have the nature look of the OS.

Comment: @user2080083 And what look and feel are you using?  The System look and feel, the cross platform look and feel or something else?

Comment: By 'nature' I guess you mean 'native'.  Use the native PLAF as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517770/jfilechooser-filters/13521592#13521592).

Comment: @MadProgrammer The System look and feel.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The code in the question states (the **AWT based)** `FileDialog`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson My bad, it was tagged Swing when I arrived :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Yes, that tag did not help to clarify things.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue when using Java 1.7.0_21. It seems that whenever you choose a filename or path that is shorter than the one you previously set with setFile(), then the new file will be returned as directory(!) by getDirectory() and getFile() returns the rest of the previous filename.
When using Java 1.6, it works as expected, so I guess this is a bug in 1.7.

**Edit:**
Fixed in:

- [Java 7u60b01](http://download.java.net/jdk7u60/changes/jdk7u60-b01.html)
  ([JDK-8024349 : FileDialog getFile returns corrupted string after previous setFile](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8024349))
  [**--> Early Access Release downloads**](https://jdk7.java.net/download.html)
- Java 8 ([JDK-8021943](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8021943))

Comment: Could you comment whether this bug fix is avaiable for higher versions of JDK ?

Comment: In 1.7.0_45 it's still the same.

Comment: Indeed. Do you know whether this bug is already listed in their QC ?

Comment: Thank you for the notice ! Do you know where can I download the ju60 with the fix ?

Comment: @XichenLi 7u60 Early Access Release can be found [here](https://jdk7.java.net/download.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is bug [JDK-8021943: FileDialog getFile returns corrupted string after previous setFile](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8021943).

Affected JVM versions: 7u5,7u15,7u21,7u25,7u40

**Fixed for Java 8**

Answer (score 0):

Function `getSaveFilePath` is fine and work as expected for me.  The problem is probably in how do you use it.  Could you please post piece of code that calls this function?

Here is how I called it:

```
public class FileDialogTest
{
    public static String getSaveFilePath(String title2)
    {
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog (new Frame (), "Save As...", 1);
        fd.setFilenameFilter (new FilenameFilter ()
        {
            public boolean accept (File dir, String name)
            {
                return name.endsWith (".mp3");
            }
        });
        fd.setFile (title2 + ".mp3");
        fd.setVisible (true);
        String str3 = fd.getFile ();
        String str4 = fd.getDirectory ();
        if (str4 == null)
            return null;
        str3 = str3.replace (".mp3", "");
        str3 = str3 + ".mp3";
        String str5 = str3;
        File localFile = new File (str4, str5);
        return localFile.getPath ();
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        String title = "NBA - In the Zone P.L. (Video by JESSExAKAxViCiOUS)";
        title = getSaveFilePath (title);
        System.out.println (title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same as your method. I've narrowed the problem down to GetFile and SetFile. When I use SetFile and set a filename longer than the one I am going to save as 'abc.mp3', then GetFile will return a string such as 'SExAKAxViCiOUS).mp3'. DID you save the file as 'abc.mp3'?